# Accordion Menu list align span outside a element

Tags: css

I am using metismenu and I need the parent category clickable. I am able to acheive this by defining the clickable element.

```
$("#menu").metisMenu({   triggerElement: '.has-arrow'});
```

The problem now is my html list layout changes from

```
<li><a class="has-child" href="http://google.com">Monitors <span class="has-arrow"></span></a><ul>...
```

to

```
<li><a class="has-child" href="http://google.com">Monitors</a> <span class="has-arrow"></span><ul>....
```

This breaks the alignment, since the span is now outside the "a" tag. How can I align the span class to the right so its inline with the "a" element?

Desired output is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can align span to right of anchor element by assigning inline-block to li element.

```css
li{

display: inline-block;

}


li .has-child{

margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<li>
<a class="has-child" href="http://google.com">Monitors</a> 
<span class="has-arrow"></span></li>>
```